# JSON loop gives one array more than expected

Tags: php

I want to output the JSON of all the JSON files I have in a directory, but for an unexpected reason it gives me **two** JSON arrays, one is wrong and one is correct.

Here's the code:

```
$files = glob("players/*");
$nFiles = count($files);

foreach($files as $file){

  $jsonArray[] = array(

    "name" => "a name",
    "reason" => "a reason",
    "date" => "a date"

  );

  echo json_encode($jsonArray);
}
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"a name","reason":"a reason","date":"a date"}] -- here the loop stops (idk why) and it begins again -- [{"name":"a name","reason":"a reason","date":"a date"},{"name":"a name","reason":"a reason","date":"a date"}]
```

Comment: Maybe you need to place your `echo` under the closing bracket from the `foreach`

Comment: DAMMIT! Didn't see it. Thank you, fella

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place the echo statement outside the foreach loop:

```
$files = glob("players/*");
$nFiles = count($files);

foreach($files as $file){

  $jsonArray[] = array(

    "name" => "a name",
    "reason" => "a reason",
    "date" => "a date"

  );
}
  echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see it.